# Detect if images have loaded in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview that is loading an image. However I am trying to call a method when the image has completed loaded / rendered.

I tried using UIWebViewDelgate and used,

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {}
```

However this method is called before the image has loaded / rendered. How can I fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Josh

Comment: What framework is this? ASP.NET?

Comment: I'm using the iPhone SDK. Sorry that I didn't make this clear.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution yet? I am struck with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think better way is use javascript to call any known url via `window.location.href='myurl://imageLoaded'` that will be intercepted in webView `shouldStartLoadingRequest`

there is way to set script for onload event [Javascript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/807878/1403732)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the delegate call you mentioned, isn't called for each HTTP request but rather for each page only.

You should be able to get notified when a certain URL request is handled by subclassing `NSURLProtocol`.  There's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572258/ios-webview-remote-html-with-local-image-files) that describes how to substitute remote images with local images in a `UIWebView`. This should give you an idea how to implement your `NSURLProtocol` subclass.