# Sniff and modify URL requests coming from UIWebViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I have one html page open inside UiWebViewController with cordova. While index.html loading inside the Uiwebviewcontroller can we sniff the requests that is originating from index.html?

for example I have following html that is getting opened in UiWebviewcontroller:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <img src="img.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I sniff and modify the url that is getting requested inside Uiwebviewcontroller ie. img.jpg,theme.css,app.js to something like content/img.jpg, css/theme.css, js/app.js using Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s possible using `NSURLProtocol`, see this [blog post by NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsurlprotocol/) and this [related Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572258/ios-webview-remote-html-with-local-image-files).