# Accessing Local file through JavaScript in embedded webbrowser (iOS)

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, html, uiwebview

Is there way to access local file system folders like Documents folder through a JavaScript that runs on a browser embedded in a native application?

I need the following

1. Load a JavaScript in a UIWebView
2. Access local file from the JavaScript running in UIWebView
3. Write local file from the JavaScript running in UIWebView

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog here: http://www.aerych.com/blog/2012/01/08/decrypting-http-streaming-video-with-nsurlprotocol/ have the answer for you.
There is a very similar question here: [iOS WebView remote html with local image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572258/ios-webview-remote-html-with-local-image-files)

If your file is an image, so no problem. I've tried with a large video then I got a memory leak (and crash) and with a shorter it simple didn't play the video.

To write a local file from javascript you may use the same way (with a different scheme), i.e. instead of "myapp://image1.png" use "writefile:// you are overloading the URLprotocol anyway.