# iOS: Open UIWebView with local javascript files

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I would like to open a website in an `UIWebView`, but I wan't to load the javascript files from the app's Documents folder (because of bandwidth). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you would need to create a custom `NSURLProtocol` as in this Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5573155/244160. Make an appropriate check in `canInitWithRequest:` and deliver your Javascript with the proper content-type according to the sample.

Update:

Here's a quick shot for a sample implementation:

```
@interface LocalJSURLProtocol : NSURLProtocol    
@end

@implementation LocalJSURLProtocol

+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{

    return [request.URL.scheme caseInsensitiveCompare:@"http"] == NSOrderedSame && [request.URL.lastPathComponent hasSuffix:@"js"]);
}

+ (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    return request;
}

- (void)startLoading
{
    NSURLRequest *request = self.request;

    NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]
                                                        MIMEType:@"text/javascript"
                                           expectedContentLength:-1
                                                textEncodingName:nil];

    NSString *localFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample.js" ofType:nil];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localFilePath];

    [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:data];
    [self.client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];

}

- (void)stopLoading
{
}

@end
```

And you register the protocol like this [`NSURLProtocol registerClass:[LocalJSURLProtocol class]];` before starting to load. This will intercept the request in your UIWebView and you have the chance to inject your own Javascript code for the request file.

Comment: This works perfectly. I used `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: jsFile]` to get localFilePath. I added the `js` files to 'Copy Bundle resources', they weren't added automatically. Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

(please see my edit below - it might be possible to work with local assets and remote html files, by using custom protocol)

It is not possible to use a local js file (or any local file) on an internet file. It is similar to the fact that you cannot open a local javascript file on a website from a regular desktop browser.

What you can do is call your website's page, save the response's html as a local html file (on your documents folder), and change the js url to be local as well. The url should be relative. 
For example:

```
documents
- myapp
-- index.html
-- scripts.js
```

inside index.html you can change the js src to be:

```
<script src="scripts.js" />
```

- comments:

  1. I assume that you can access and edit the webpage.
  2. You can do a nice fallback in case the local js file was not downloaded. Similar to jQuery's cdn fallback to local file, we can do the opposite thing and do a fallback to server's file (jQuery is just for example. It can be done with any js file just by testing for namespace's existence:

> ```
>     <script src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
> <script>
> if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
>     document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js'
> ```
>
> type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
>       }

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**:

After reviewing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572258/ios-webview-remote-html-with-local-image-files/5573155#5573155), you might be able to access local files from remote html file (in his example he is working with local html file, but it might work with a remote on as well)