# NSURLProtocol vs NSURLCache for JavaScript to Native iOS bridge

Tags: ios, hybrid-mobile-app

Subclassing NSURLProtocol and NSURLCache appear to be two established approaches to allowing JavaScript communication from a UIWebView to native iOS code.

Both allow you to intercept NSURLRequests made by a UIWebView and return arbitrary response data.

Both techniques have performance sufficient for my requirements.

So, performance time aside, is there any reason why I should prefer one approach over the other?

For reference an example using NSURLProtocol and an example using NSURLCache:

[iOS WebView remote html with local image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572258/ios-webview-remote-html-with-local-image-files)

http://www.handcraftedsoftware.net/articles/how-to-pass-messages-between-native-ios-and-a-uiwebview-via-ajax-without-phonegap