# How to display the Authentication Challenge in UIWebView for local network url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to access a secure for local network url through `UIWebView`. When I access it through safari, i get an authentication challenge but the same does not appear in my `UIWebView` in the application. How can I make it appear?

E.g. http://292.168.1.54/TestWeb/Test.pdf

This url working in safari browser but the same url does not appear in my `UIWebView`.

Any pointers, sample code or links will be very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get to the authentication (in your case probably basic auth) challenge.

1. `-[UIWebViewDelegate webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:]` will give you the request. Now you just start a second request to the same URL and use `[NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:]` to get the challenge. Then you present a dialog and ask the user for credentials. Save the credentials in `NSURLCredentialStorage` and then reload the page.
2. [Create a subclass of `NSURLProtocol`](http://nshipster.com/nsurlprotocol/) that handles http and https. Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572258/ios-webview-remote-html-with-local-image-files) and get the authentication challenge there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you.

- (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
      self.webView.delegate = self;

  ```
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://skinC.com/abc/"];// here you can write your url that you want to open
      NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [self.webView loadRequest:requestURL];

        AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


      [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];}
  ```